# dynamic programming algorithm to decide whether or not there exist a tree with the sequence of leafs given a set of binary trees of height 1

Tags: algorithm, tree, binary-tree, dynamic-programming

I am trying to solve the following problem. I won't lie it's homework. I am not asking for the answer but at least for some tips and how I can start thinking about the problem.

A binary tree having each node labeled with an integer is said to be labeled. Sketch a dynamic
programming algorithm solving the following problem :

Given: sequence b1; ... ; bm of integers and labeled binary trees T1; ... ; Tk of height 1

Decide: if there exists a labeled binary tree having as each of its height-1 subtrees some Ti (with
repetitions permitted) and having b1; ... ; bm as the labels of its leaves.

The following hint is given:
Draw inspiration from the matrix chaining algorithm and think of a table having as
each entry a set of integers pertaining in some way to a subsequence bi; ... ; bi+s.